# using DDL - change 'Select' to 'Null' when viewing drop down

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-select

Using MVC I am displaying a list 'DeliveryRunList' through a drop down.

'Select' being the option the user sees, if the user clicks the drop down and selects 'select' as their choice, it will store the value as NULL, this is fine.

However is there anyway to change 'Select' to 'No Value' when the drop down is clicked so it will store as empty, but yet still appear as 'select' before the drop down is clicked.

```
 <div class="editor-label">@Html.DropDownList("DeliveryRunId", Model.DeliveryRunList, "Select")</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery to achieve this easily:

```
$(function () {
    $('#DeliveryRunId').focus(function () {
        $('#DeliveryRunId option:first-child').text('No Value');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem recently, but instead of going for JQuery as Mike said (which is also a nice way of doing the task), i manually added it to the selectlist of the DropdownListFor Html helper from the controller and put it in the Viewbag and send it to it.

```
    List<SelectListItem> DropDownValues= new List<SelectListItem>();
    DropDownValues.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "-Select-", Value = "No Value" });
    DropDownValues.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text 1", Value = "1.ToString()" });
    DropDownValues.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Text 2", Value = "2.ToString()" });

    ViewBag.DropDownValueList= new SelectList(DropDownValues, "Value", "Text");
```

And in your View,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DropDownName, (SelectList)ViewBag.DropDownValueList)
```

I didn't check this code, but i remember doing like this and it should work.. Let me know if it does..